# RDLC tablix group footer as page footer

Tags: rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to create a report for printing of checks/payment confirmation.  The check itself is at the top of the page, shows detail in the middle (1-N records), and includes additional text which is fixed at the bottom of the page.  The text at the bottom contains data associated with the check itself.

I attempted to create a tablix, using a group header for the check itself, and the detail for the individual line detail, but haven't been able to align the tablix footer to the page bottom.

When attempting to use the page footer section, I cannot access my dataset.

I don't think I'm the first person to attempt similar functionality, but I cannot seem to find any suggestions.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Page Footer is the necessary location to achieve absolute page bottom positioning, but requires a secondary step to access the data from the current data.

The footer is able to access Report Items, but not the dataset, which in my situation required the addition of a hidden field to the main body.  The Page Footer could then reference that hidden field for it's value.

**Object 1 / Tablix**

```
Name:  FieldRequiredByFooter
Value: DataSetProperty
```

**Object 2 / Page Footer**

```
Name:  FooterField
Expression: =ReportItems!FieldRequiredByFooter.Value
```

If your page contains a listing of data, rather than a single item, the expression needs to be modified similar to

```
=First(ReportItems!FieldRequiredByFooter.Value)
```

Additional information at
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252093(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Tried this solution, but I'm getting the error "An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item." This even though I am using the First() function to refer to a report item inside a tablix on my page.

Comment: Not sure.  I think you have to define a group and then use the footer only in the group.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms251786%28v%3dvs.90%29