# How to display group footer at bottom of the page - rdlc reports

Tags: rdlc

I am trying to create a simple page in Microsoft RDLC reports using visual studio 2010, on this page i have created group header and group footer. I want to show the group footer at the bottom of the page. Please view the attached image. In image i have used arrows for better understanding. Please anyone guide and help, thanks

[image: Rdlc Report Image]

Comment: Could you please also show use the rdlc Template?

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454646/rdlc-tablix-group-footer-as-page-footer) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141489/how-to-add-group-footer-in-vs2010-rdlc-report) if you want to bring just textbox to footer only on last page then try [this](https://dileepakb.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/how-to-print-page-footer-at-bottom-and-on-last-page-of-a-rdlc-report-in-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2013-r2/), Hope Helps.

Comment: What a pain. Finally solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979294/rdlc-page-footer-not-displaying-visual-studio-2008).